# mvc2 multiple content place holders

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

multiple content place holders..1 with a text entry box and a submit button..
the second content place holder has several options in..
when i perform the submit the options from the 2nd place holder aren't getting passed through.
can you suggest a method on how i can perform this submission passing all values to my controller?
the values outside the 1st place holder are getting set to null.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i resolve the problem with your help!

```
    $('#indexform').submit(function (ev) {
    $('#hiddenField').attr('value', $('input[name=CheckboxOption]:checked').val());
    return true;
});

    <fieldset>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(searchCriteria => searchCriteria.Database, new { id = "hiddenField" })%>
    </fieldset>
```